# I want to display data only once

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column in my table that has many numbers that are the same, I must first explain these aren't duplicate entries. What I want I do when I do a query is to be able to show the numbers that are the same only once.

In the example below I have a list of numbers several of which are exactly the same.

1.9.1000229.3

1.9.1000229.3

1.2.1000414.3

1.222.1000503.3

1.222.1000503.3

1.222.1000503.4

1.13.1000503.6

1.13.1000503.6

1.13.1000503.6

1.26.1000503.2

1.26.1000503.2

1.26.1000503.2

1.26.1000503.2

I want to display this list so only one of these same numbers shows up after a query like this below.

1.9.1000229.3

1.2.1000414.3

1.222.1000503.3

1.222.1000503.4

1.13.1000503.6

1.26.1000503.2

What would be the query to do this? Im using Microsoft SQL Server MAnagement Studio 2008 thx paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct data from table order by data
```

--The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

Comment: thx but im having trouble adding this code with other colums in table

Comment: Then use `where count(col)=1`